# how to reduce unusable LVM PV size to minimum?

Tags: lvm

When I use LVM to partition one or more storages I noticed it use 4 MiB' blocks (physical extent) by default, while the storage itself usually uses 512 bytes per sector.

I believed it should not be a problem if I align the LVM partitions to 4 MiB, but no matter what size they be, it will always show some "not usable" size when run `pvdisplay`:

```
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda2
VG Name               xpto
PV Size               17.00 GiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              4351
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          4351
PV UUID               xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx
```

But even if I reallocate the PV to match the size minus the not usable, it decrease the total PE and still have remaining not usable size. Even using `pvdisplay --unit B` to see the exact number.

I'm wondering what is the exact size of the LVM header, I read some text arguing it would be 4 sectors of 512 bytes, other saying it is 180 KiB, but I have tried all combinations and was not able to discover how it is calculated.

Is there a way to align the PV partition in order to zero the not usable size, or at least reduce to minimum?

Comment: I would swear storage has not been using 512 bytes for quite sometime now. The distribution/usage of files vs sectors is highly dependent also in what fs you are using on top of lvm

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have read somewhere it could be [4096 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector) as well, but I believe it depend on vendor, or maybe could be customized, anyway in my case it is 512 bytes for sure.

Comment: Exact partition size `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda2`? Perhaps some kind of rounding error? I get for example `PV Size               401.00 MiB / not usable 0` so it works for me. The extra 1.00MiB is the default metadata size (1st PE Offset). If the size is correct, which distro, version of kernel / lvm2 / ...?

Comment: Answer I wrote just yesterday to a similar question, may be of interest https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460387/30851

Comment: That 4 MB is about 0.023 % of the size of the whole PV. Are you sure it's worth spending the effort to try to recover it?

Comment: @ilkkachu I want to know in order to do not make this mistake anymore, in new installations, knowledge is never too much.

Comment: @frostschutz you have the correct answer, the header size is 1MiB, could you please write it as answer in order to me mark it as correct?

Comment: " in late 2009, accelerating in 2010 and hitting mainstream in 2011, hard drive companies are migrating away from the legacy sector size of 512 bytes to a larger, more efficient sector size of 4096 bytes, generally referred to as 4K sectors" ... are you sure those 512 bytes are just not a logical view/compatibility layer? check your hw datasheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those devices which sector size is 4K probably your device will never get unaligned, but for those with 512 bytes you should align the partition's first sector to match one divisible by 4096 bytes, in that case, divisible by 8 (4096/512), but remember that it starts with zero.